# Show android SearchView EditText by default

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I am using a SearchView in android. When I first land on the page, all that is visible is the search icon. Then when I click on the icon, the EditText appears. How do I get the EditText to be visible from the get go? Here is my xml:

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT---

Oh sorry! I tought you wanted to do an 'empty' query.
I think you can open SearchView programmatically using:

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
```

OLD ANSWER--

Inside an Activity you can try with:

```
onSearchRequested();
```

And inside a Fragment you can try with:

```
getActivity().onSearchRequested();
```

Good luck!

Comment: thanks I came here to post my answer: `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"`. You got it first. Thanks.

Comment: do you know the answer to this follow up question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981613/setting-iconified-to-false-on-android-searchview-cause-view-to-not-be-searchable

Answer (score 1):

From the [official Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html):

> If you want the search field to always be visible, then call
>   setIconifiedByDefault(false).

This **does** work for the compatibility `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
// Expand the search view
searchItem.expandActionView();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set this property for click event

```
searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchCloseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchEditText.setText("");
                ((SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view)).setIconified(false);
            }
        });
```