# Setting iconified to false on android SearchView cause view to not be searchable

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

This question is a follow up to [Show android SearchView EditText by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979238/show-android-searchview-edittext-by-default). My SearchView used to work fine until I added `android:iconifiedByDefault="false"` to the layout. Now, when I click on the icon or type in the search field, no search takes place. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? here is my SearchView as it exists now.

```
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I already tried the following:

```
mSearch.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onSearchRequested();
        //other stuff happen here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if (hasFocus) { ...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem by simply adding **requestFocus** tag in SearchView widget.

```
    <SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:queryHint="Enter Song name.."
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false">

    <requestFocus/>

</SearchView>
```