# Im not getting the underline of search view control in the toolbar layout

Tags: java, android, material-design

[This is the menu item for search view widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksq6z.png)

[this is what I am getting in my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNGaO.png)

Comment: I am new to the android ..  hanging up with this one for  many days..

Comment: Please review your question and read the [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 0):

Activity file:
For the more detail please read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27482902/3678308) .

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);

         MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        SearchView searchView = null;
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(MainActivity.this.getComponentName()));
        }
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `searchView.setIconified(false);` This will show EditText on opening the screen with searchView.

You can see here for the details: [Show android SearchView EditText by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979238/show-android-searchview-edittext-by-default)